# Move Magento Category Select to Above Product List and Add Thumbnails

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to remove Category from the left-side attribute navigation and add it above the product list view.

I've already unset it from catalog.leftnav using local.xml like so:

```
<layout>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

But I'm pretty stumped as to how to get it back above the products. And once I do...I'm not quite sure where the code is run that generates the category list. In other words, where I can edit it to include $cat->getImageUrl() and such for my thumbnails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now after removing from left, you should add to content area adjusting it's position with `before`/`after`.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
  <reference name="content">
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="category.products" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```